# Xcode Step Over behaving like Step Out

Tags: objective-c, xcode, adobe-illustrator

The debugger in Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002) is behaving oddly whenever I try to Step Over a line of code like the following that uses the -> operator:

```
AIErr err = sAIGroup->NormalizeCompoundPath(art,kAINormalizeCompoundPathBest);
```

Many of these function calls are from Adobe Illustrator's SDK.

Research I've done so far:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/547897?start=0&tstart=0: No resolution and it was back on Xcode 2.3 anyway, a long time ago.
- [Why does using "Step over" feature in XCode debugger hide issue with weak property that ought to be strong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357280/why-does-using-step-over-feature-in-xcode-debugger-hide-issue-with-weak-proper): I'm not sure this is relevant because the variable sAIGroup doesn't seem to be declared as a weak property, but I'm not really sure I understand it well enough.

So how can I get Step Over to behave as Step Over and not as Step Out?

Comment: Might need to include a little surrounding code for this one.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I'll see if I can get something concise but it happens consistently on lines of code that use the -> operator where the thing to the left of the operator is part of Adobe Illustrator's SDK.  Sorry I don't know the right terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: set breakpoint after the line of code that uses -> and just click the button on the debugger that continues to that line.  If you're dealing with code that's got a lot of loops or recursive calls, then write if() statements to isolate the conditions you want and break in those if() statements.